# Limit SQL Primary Key to certain ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to make the autoincrementing Primary Key of my table to only be in the ranges 1-12, 101-112, 201-212, etc.

This is because I have a series of repeating items that are 12 in a set and then you get another set, having them indexed in this way by the Primary Kay would be most easy, I think.

Is it possible?

Comment: It wouldn't be most easy to index it by PK. Leave PK as it is, autoincremented and then create another column which you update from a trigger / stored procedure / scheduled event (whichever you find easiest to work with) and index that one. Tampering with PK like you want can only have negative effects.

Comment: just create another column that is mod 12 the primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the right way to approach what you are doing. If you have repeating items in a "set", then add a column to the table to specify the set. This is the sensible way to handle the data. It makes the structure of the data in the table more explicit.

Then, if you really want to use a primary key encoded with a value, what is so hard about:

```
select floor((primarykey - 1) / 12) as setvalue
```

I don't recommend this, because auto-incremented ids are not guaranteed to be gapless, but it would work under most circumstances.

Finally, if you really want to do what you are proposing you would need a trigger. This seems like a bad reason to write a trigger, because there are better alternatives.

Comment: `floor( x / 12) + 1` to go from 1-12 -- I think you have 0-11 there.

Comment: @Hogan . . . This identifies the "set" as the first digit(s) in the primary key.  That does start with "0" in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is not directly possible, you can make it work by having a primary key composed of two fields - an unrestricted integer designating a group, and another integer restricted to values 1..12 designating a number within a group.

However, this is not a very good approach, because it necessarily gives your primary key some *meaning* outside your database model. This is bad, because it makes it easy to exploit this meaning in the code, which in turn makes it a lot harder to refactor your database.